# Angular 9 - Meta description, and keyword isn't working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, seo, meta-tags, keyword-search

I am pretty much new for creating an Angular none dashboard projects, and making them SEO friendly.

The first thing that come to the game is having title, and meta data such as description, and keywords on each view/page.
I found [angular meta tags](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-set-html-meta-tags-using-angular-4/) as a solution. However, using advanced search operator such as ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
‍‍‍`site:mysite.com‍` ‍‍shows no outcome. There must be some wrong in my wiring.

ّOn each component that loads in route I have the following

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
            selector: 'app-privacy-policy',
            templateUrl: './privacy-policy.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./privacy-policy.component.scss']
})

export class PrivacyPolicyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private meta: Meta,
          private titleService: Title) { }

    ngOnInit() {
                this.titleService.setTitle('VIP CPA | Privacy Policy');
                this.meta.addTag({
                                  name: 'description',
                                  content: 'Privacy Policy of you at VIP CPA is important to us. ' +
                                           'This page provides detailed information of our privacy '+ 
                                            'policy'
                                  }, true);

               this.meta.addTag({ name: 'keywords', content: 'Accountant, Downtown, Montreal, Tax, + 
                                        'Individual Taxation, Personal Tax, Tax deduction, Payroll,'+  
                                         'Bookkeeping, Financial statement, Privacy Policy'
                               }, true);

               this.meta.addTag({
                                 name: 'robots',
                                 content: 'index, follow'
                                }, true);
                               }
 }
```

and `site:vipcpa.ca` gives me selected paragraphs from those pages.

Comment: Is the meta description showing up on your website when you load it?

Comment: interestingly no: view-source:https://vipcpa.ca/privacy-policy

Comment: I see the title, and I see the robots. why? I have no typo

Comment: however homepage has a same coding, and shows meta tag in advance search operator
site:vipcpa.ca

Comment: Should I add something root of project or in app?